# Switch between multiple materials on a button press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to have an object in my scene change between two different materials at run time, when ever a button is pressed in my Unity project. However, I have never done this before and I'm having an issue getting my head around how to do this.

In my scene I have one game object I've called my controller. This script holds my material switching class and is looking like this:

```
public GameObject cupMesh;
bool isOn = true;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    cupMesh = GameObject.Find("CupMesh");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10, 100, 40), "Show mesh"))
    {

        renderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I know this doesn't change the material, but the above code does nothing. I've never modified anything on the mesh renderer before but I know there is a list of materials on it.

How can I access that list so I can have my program switch between the two materials found there?

Comment: Sometimes documentation is very useful, just do a little effort to search inside the doc and you will get pretty explanatory examples for your purposes http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material-mainTexture.html

Answer (score 0):

To show or hide a gameObject, rather than using render.enabled property, you should use this:

```
// Unactivates the game object.
gameObject.SetActive (false);
```

However it's not clear from the code if you want to adjust the material of the object the script is attached to, or the cupMesh game object.

If you wanted to make the cupMesh disappear, you would use:

```
cupMesh.SetActive (false);
```

Or if you wanted to access the material component of the cupMesh, this is

```
cupMesh.renderer.material
```